Are Jews permitted to play jacks on Shabbat
According to Halacha is it permitted for Jews to play jacks on Shabbat? Or no, would it involve any issur like muktzeh or anything else? Does it depend on if it’s a minor chinuch age or an adult?

Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchata 16:11 writes that playing five stones, a form of jacks, is permissible on Shabbos.
